# What partitions are associated to each os?

Tags: 14.04, gparted

I have 3 OS's on my computer, the primary one in ubuntu, the second one is windows and the third is kali linux.

I want to delete kali, but I have a little problem with that - I don't know which partitions are associated with ubuntu and which are associated with windows/kali so I'm afraid to delete the wrong partition.

Is there a way to find what partitions are associated to a specific OS? - from ubuntu of course.

Here's an image of the partitions:
http://postimg.org/image/3mxml4cfj/

Thanks for reading and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ntfs partitions are used by windows and ext partitions are where  Linux systems are installed.

If the snapshot was taken from Ubuntu, then the /dev/sda7 which is mounted at / is the Ubuntu partition. The other partition /dev/sda8 which is alsoext4 must be Kali Linux.

To make sure, enter the Kali Linux and in terminal type the command lsblk - l. This will show you all the partitions and where each one is mounted. The partition mounted at / will be your culprit!

If you are not familiar with terminal you can use gparted in Kali Linux to find out the same.

Comment: hmmmm but what about the linux-swap partition? how would I know to which OS it is associated?

Comment: Run lsblk if the swap partition shows [SWAP] flag on the mountpoint then swap belongs to Ubuntu.

Comment: If the swap is in use, there would be a lock symbol next to it in gparted. Also on right click it will show swapoff command. In your case the swap partition does not seem to be locked. So it belongs to Kali Linux.

Comment: Swap is unformatted disk, so it could be that `swapoff` was issued in Ubuntu OR `swapon` was issued in Kali... I wouldn't erase (the also very small) swap but use it in Ubuntu after deletion of Kali...

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... mount each partition, take a look around & see what's on it?

All the NTFS ones are either windows or storage formatted by windows. sda2 looks like an EFI partition.

9's apparently a linux swap. Take a look at each linux's `/etc/fstab` and see which one uses sda9 for swap... could be both, I think I read somewhere that some linux's might start using whatever swap's available.

7 is whatever OS you were running at the time of the image (mounted `/`). So 8 would be the other linux.

But I'd definitely take a look inside one, backup any wanted data & such, before deleting any.

And GRUB's boot menu should point to each one's partition too, but I'm not sure if it uses the same labels or numbering.

Comment: And what about the linux-swap partition? Does it belong to kali or ubuntu? This is the part that confuses me, everything else is pretty obvious.